# Howto setup eslint with airbnb in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, eslint

I'm a Linux web developer and I'm trying to help my brother setting up eslint with airbnb's linting rules but on Visual Studio 2015 on the Windows machine that he is using.

We want to use the following C:\Users\username.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": [2, "never"]
  }
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 includes the APS.NET Core Tooling module that in turn includes Node.js with eslint. We are having troubles getting any errors displaying in real time. It seem to work with *extends: "defaults/configurations/airbnb/es6"* but with that configuration there are errors about configuration properties that has been renamed.

Are there any Microsoft based web developers out there that knows how to set this up in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: ya that is a problem with the setup https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/727

Comment: Sounds like your brother renamed the files. Try having him uninstall the web tooling, reinstall, and use the same extends property in the `.eslintrc`

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for days... I left a comment on a couple github issues but it seems like this is being pretty widely ignored at the moment.